# LINQ to XML question

Tags: linq

My requirement here is to retrieve the node that matches the hostname (for eg. machine1) and I always get back no results. Please let me know what the problem is?

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

```
XDocument configXML = XDocument.Load("the below xml");

var q = from s in configXML.Descendants("lcsetting")
    where ((string)s.Element("host") == hostName)                        
    select s;
```

The actual xml:

```
<lcsettings>
  <lcsetting env="prod">
    <hosts usagelogpath="">
      <host>machine1</host>
      <host>machine2</host>
      <host>machine3</host>
    </hosts>
  </lcsetting>
  <lcsetting env="qa">
    <hosts usagelogpath="">
      <host>machine4</host>
      <host>machine5</host>
      <host>machine6</host>
    </hosts>
  </lcsetting>
  <lcsetting env="test">
    <hosts usagelogpath="">
      <host>machine7</host>
      <host>machine8</host>
      <host>machine9</host>
    </hosts>
  </lcsetting>
</lcsettings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a `host` element directly under an lcsetting - that doesn't occur because there's always a `hosts` element between the two in the hierarchy. You're also using `Element` instead of `Elements`, which means only the first element with the right name will be returned.

You could use `Descendants` again instead of `Element`... but you'll need to change the condition. Something like:

```
var q = from s in configXML.Descendants("lcsetting")
        where s.Descendants("host").Any(host => host.Value == hostName)
        select s;
```

Alternatively, you could make your query find `host` elements and then take the grandparent element in each case:

```
var q = from host in configXML.Descendants("host")
        where host.Value == hostName
        select host.Parent.Parent;
```

(This assumes a host element will only occur once per `lcsetting`; if that's not the case, you can add a call to `Distinct`.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also, Is it possible to retrieve a default lcsetting element (say "qa") if the query returns no results.

Answer (score 1):

"host" is not a child of "lcsetting".

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have a <hosts> tag immedieately below your lcsetting, that contains your <host> tags. <host> is not an immedieate child of <lcsetting>.

This query will work:

```
var q = from s in configXML.Descendants("lcsetting").SelectMany(lcSetting => lcSetting.Descendants("host"))
        where s.Name == "host" && s.Value == hostName
        select s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting the descendants lcsetting but then attempting to check the element host which is two levels below it. The Element() function references only child elements 1 level deep. I'd recommend changing this to:

```
XDocument configXML = XDocument.Load("the below xml");
var q = from s in configXML.Descendants("lcsetting") 
        where s.Descendants("host").SingleOrDefault(e => e.Value == hostname) != null
        select s;
```